# change text color in dark theme in lfutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx, flutter-theme

I have defined a separate class for `TextTheme` and defined the desired `textStyle`, assigning it to the `ThemeData` for both light and dark themes, as shown in the image. However, the textColor is not being applied in the dark mode.

When I use two separate TextTheme classes to define styles, it works correctly, but it requires writing more code.

I want to apply color styles to both light and dark themes using a single code source for styling. how can i do this? (i use getx)

my TextTheme:

```
class MyTextTheme {
  static const String fontFamily = 'Vazir';
  static TextTheme myTextTheme = TextTheme(
    titleLarge: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 25,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
        color: Get.isDarkMode
            ? Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 242, 231)
            : Color.fromARGB(255, 137, 116, 253)),
//
```

my Theme

```
  static final lightTheme = ThemeData(
      buttonTheme: const ButtonThemeData(
        buttonColor: Colors.green,
      ),
      primaryColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 62, 104, 167),
// elevetedButtom style
      elevatedButtonTheme: MyButtonStyle.myElevetedButton,
// primery colors
      colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      ),
      fontFamily: MyTextTheme.fontFamily,
      brightness: Brightness.light,
      // useMaterial3: true,
// text styles
      textTheme: MyTextTheme.myTextTheme);

  //!dark theme propertys
  static final darkTheme = ThemeData(
    //elevetedButton Style
    elevatedButtonTheme: MyButtonStyle.myElevetedButton,
    fontFamily: MyTextTheme.fontFamily,
    colorScheme: ColorScheme.dark(),
    textTheme: MyTextTheme.myTextTheme,
  );
}
```

Change theme code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOzJD.png)

I have clarified that the problem is with the `textColor`, not the textStyle as a whole.
I have clarified that using two separate `TextTheme` classes is a workaround, but it is not ideal.

Comment: This is standard practice to separate white and dark theme styling. I think your implementation is okay.

Comment: MyTextTheme.myTextTheme is static and only created once, isn't it?

Comment: yes it is. but i dont now why it dosn't work... the text color in dark mode dosn't change

Answer (score 0):

## Because [lightTheme.textTheme] and [dartTheme.textTheme] are the same

It declares the same [textTheme] at the beginning

```dart
class MyTextTheme {
  static TextTheme myTextTheme = TextTheme(
    titleLarge: TextStyle(
      color: Get.isDarkMode ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
    ),
  );
}

final lightTheme = ThemeData(
  // titleLarge.color is Colors.white
  textTheme: MyTextTheme.myTextTheme, 
);

final darkTheme = ThemeData(
  // titleLarge.color is also Colors.white (not Colors.black)
  textTheme: MyTextTheme.myTextTheme, 
);
```

It just switches the theme from [lightTheme] to [darkTheme]

```dart
Get.changeThemeMode(ThemeMode.dark);
```

## You can change `myTextTheme` to function

```dart
class MyTextTheme {
  /// Returns a TextTheme that changes the color of the titleLarge text style
  /// depending on the current theme mode.
  static TextTheme getTextTheme(ThemeMode mode) {
    return TextTheme(
      titleLarge: TextStyle(
        /// The color of the text is white in light mode and black in dark mode.
        color: mode == ThemeMode.dark ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
      ),
    );
  }
}

/// The light theme uses the MyTextTheme.getTextTheme(ThemeMode.light) method
/// to create a TextTheme with a white titleLarge text style.
final lightTheme = ThemeData(
  textTheme: MyTextTheme.getTextTheme(ThemeMode.light),
);

/// The dark theme uses the MyTextTheme.getTextTheme(ThemeMode.dark) method
/// to create a TextTheme with a black titleLarge text style.
final darkTheme = ThemeData(
  textTheme: MyTextTheme.getTextTheme(ThemeMode.dark),
);
```